# SwiftUI - Display details view of a Place in fullScreenCover

Tags: swiftui, binding, maps, state, fullscreen

I wanted to display my PlacesView in fullScreenCover when a isInfoWindowVisible is set to true and selectedItem is not nil. I think bindings between views and components is wrong at some place. Below is my code. How can I fix so my PlacesView is displayed after isInfoWindowVisible is true and selectedItem is not nil?

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: Place?
    @State private var selectedLocationIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var isPickerVisible = false
    @State private var isShowUser: Bool = false
    @State private var isShowHighScore: Bool = false
    @State private var showButtonTitle = "Show locations"
    @State private var navigateButtonTitle = "Show routes"
    @State private var userButtonTitle = "User"
    @State private var highScoreButtonTitle = "High score"
    @State private var isZoomedIn = false
    @State private var isNavigating = false
    @State private var showNavigationView = false
    @State private var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    let items: [Place]
    
    @State private var isInfoWindowVisible: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapViewContent(selectedItem: $selectedItem, selectedLocationIndex: $selectedLocationIndex, isZoomedIn: $isZoomedIn, userHighScore: .constant(0), isInfoWindowVisible: isInfoWindowVisible, items: items)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    VStack(spacing: 10){
                        FloatingActionButton(imageName: "list.number", backgroundColor: .clear, foregroundColor: .white, action: {
                            isShowHighScore.toggle()
                        }).fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowHighScore) {
                            HighScore()
                        }
                        
                        FloatingActionButton(imageName: "person.fill", backgroundColor: .clear, foregroundColor: .white, action: {
                            isShowUser.toggle()
                        }).fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowUser) {
                            AccountView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            CustomButton(title: $showButtonTitle, backgroundColor: Color("ButtonColor")) {
                isPickerVisible.toggle()
                showButtonTitle = isPickerVisible ? "Hide Locations" : "Show Locations"
            }
            .padding(12)
            
            if isPickerVisible {
                Picker("Select Location", selection: $selectedLocationIndex) {
                    ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(items[index].place)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                .padding()
                .onReceive([selectedLocationIndex].publisher.first()) { _ in
                    self.isZoomedIn = true
                }
            }
            
            if isNavigating {
                // Show navigation instructions here
                // Implement your navigation UI or view
                NavigationView {
                    NavigationInstructionsView(destinationCoordinate: $destinationCoordinate)
                }
            } else {
                CustomButton(title: $navigateButtonTitle, backgroundColor: Color("ButtonColor")){
                    if selectedLocationIndex < items.count {
                        destinationCoordinate = items[selectedLocationIndex].coordinate
                        self.isNavigating = true
                        self.showNavigationView = true // Show the NavigationView
                    }
                }
                .padding(12)
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isInfoWindowVisible) {
            if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
                PlacesView(item: selectedItem, selectedImage: .constant(nil))
            } else {
                // Handle the case when selectedItem is nil, such as showing a placeholder view or taking some other appropriate action.
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait
                windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            }
            Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [
                AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "MapView",
                AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "MapView"
            ])
        }
        .onReceive([isInfoWindowVisible].publisher.first()) { newValue in
            // Handle isInfoWindowVisible state changes here
            if newValue {
                // The info window is visible, you can perform actions when it's shown
                self.isInfoWindowVisible = newValue
                print("New value \(self.isInfoWindowVisible)")
                print(newValue)
            } else {
                // The info window is no longer visible, you can perform actions when it's closed
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(items: Locations.items)
    }
}

struct MapViewContent: View {
    @Binding var selectedItem: Place?
    @Binding var selectedLocationIndex: Int
    @Binding var isZoomedIn: Bool
    @Binding var userHighScore: Int
    @State var isInfoWindowVisible: Bool = false
    @State private var isNavigating: Bool = false
    @State private var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    let items: [Place]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MapViewContainer(
                selectedItem: $selectedItem,
                selectedLocationIndex: $selectedLocationIndex,
                userHighScore: userHighScore,
                destinationCoordinate: $destinationCoordinate,
                isNavigating: $isNavigating,
                isInfoWindowVisible: $isInfoWindowVisible,
                items: items
            )
        }
    }
}
struct MapViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    private let zoom: Float = 18.0
    @Binding var selectedItem: Place?
    @Binding var selectedLocationIndex: Int
    @State var userHighScore: Int = 0
    @Binding var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @Binding var isNavigating: Bool
    @Binding var isInfoWindowVisible: Bool
    let items: [Place]
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapCoordinator {
        MapCoordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude, zoom: zoom)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
        mapView.settings.rotateGestures = true
        mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
        mapView.settings.tiltGestures = true
        mapView.isIndoorEnabled = true
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = true
        mapView.mapType = .hybrid
        if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mapStyle", withExtension: "json") {
            if let style = try? GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL) {
                mapView.mapStyle = style
            }
        }
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
        // Remove existing markers from the map
        mapView.clear()
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        
        if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
            // Lock the camera on the selected item
            let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(selectedItem.coordinate, zoom: zoom)
            mapView.animate(with: cameraUpdate)
        }
        
        for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = item.coordinate
            marker.title = item.place
            marker.snippet = item.adress
            let customMarkerImage = UIImage(named: item.image)
            let width: CGFloat =  30
            let height: CGFloat =  60
            let resizedImage = customMarkerImage?.resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: width, height: height), circle: true)
            marker.icon = resizedImage
            marker.map = mapView
            
            if index == selectedLocationIndex {
                // Customize the appearance of the selected marker
            }
            
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(item.coordinate)
        }
    }
}
class MapCoordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    var parent: MapViewContainer
    
    init(_ parent: MapViewContainer) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didCloseInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        if let userData = marker.userData as? Int,
        let selectedPlace = parent.items.first(where: { $0.id == userData }) {
            // Calculate the distance between the user and the selected location
            let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: parent.locationManager.latitude, longitude: parent.locationManager.longitude)
            let selectedLocation = CLLocation(latitude: selectedPlace.coordinate.latitude, longitude: selectedPlace.coordinate.longitude)
            let distance = userLocation.distance(from: selectedLocation)
            print("User locations \(userLocation)")
            print("Selected locations \(selectedLocation)")
            print("Distance  \(distance)")
            if distance <= 50.0 {  // Within 50 meters
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.isInfoWindowVisible = true // Show the PlacesView
                    self.parent.selectedItem = selectedPlace
                    print("Coordinator \(self.parent.isInfoWindowVisible)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).